# Generating java POCOs and populating them by reading json file, all dynamically

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to Android app development and I am stuck at a point where in my app I need to dynamically create class, define its attributes and populate them all dynamically.

This dynamic thing is required because the json file changes every time, a click event is fired and I need to populate a `recyclerView`, getting header and respective values from that json file.

I have come across few solutions like using javassist library and using hashmap (though I didn't get this one).

Comment: How do you mean changes every time? Do you mean that JSON keys in key-value pairs change every time?

Comment: yes, because a new json file is downloaded everytime. so keys and its value, everything changes.

Comment: @RojyKumari So you need to dynamically parse the JSON which you received from server and parse it into its respective classes. Like Integer, Strings and Hashmap in case of json object?

Comment: @RobinsGupta No, not exactly. I need to dynamically parse  that json to POCOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found it.

You want to parse the JSONObject at runtime and get its keys. And you don't know what structure the JSONObject would have.

Just use this `Json helper` class [JSON HELPER](https://gist.github.com/codebutler/2339666)

To convert JSONObject use `JsonHelper.toMap(JSONObject object)` given there.

```
//Now to get the keys
for ( String key : hashMapObject.keySet() ) {
    System.out.println( key );
} 




//Here hashMapObject is generated from `JsonHelper.toMap` method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Retrofit` library and everything will get handled automatically and very easily [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit)

Just follow these steps to use Retrofit

**First Download and Integrate Retrofit to your android project.**

```
//In your Gradle file. Add this line.

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
```

**Now suppose you want to implement a `Get` request** from a URL lets say

`https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos.` 
To get all the repository listed on `GitHub`. Here `{user}` will be username

So your base URL here is `https://api.github.com` and path for 
Get Is `/users/{user}/repos`

**Now create an interface.**

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}



Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.github.com").build();
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

//Each Call from the created GitHubService can make a synchronous or asynchronous HTTP request to the remote webserver.
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("robinskumar73");
```

Comment: Repo is a predefined class here, ryt?

Comment: Key:Value pairs always change so your Repo must be some dynamic object or simply it wont work.